# Failed to resolve:com.google.firebase:firebasse

Tags: firebase, gradle, firebase-crash-reporting

In my app, I am trying to use Firebase crash10.2.1, but I cannot get gradle to compile. I keep getting the message :

> 'Failed to resolve:com.google.firebase:firebasse'

Comment: Please add more detail. What have you tried so far? Where does your code error?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when I tried to use firebase-messaging:10.2.0 and to fix that I did this:

On Android studio, go to the menu bar and click on Tools > Android > SDK Manager.

Click on the SDK Tools tab

check the Google Play services box as well as the Google Repository box.

Click on apply, it will prompt you before applying the new updates.

Click Ok and wait for the download

Sync your project again and everything is fine.

also check for correct version